# Why Word 2007 started to number pages from beginning after page 21?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, numbering

I have a document where I have setup page numbers for footer. This is all working fine until page 21. After that the page number is restarted for unknown reason from 2. I don't see any special char to delete. I wish page numbering to continue all the way.

**EDIT 1**

It turns out, I have a layout with 2 column display, and this 2 columns display introduces two more sections, and so the page numbering is restarted.

So now the question is, how can I keep the 2 column layout for the selection, and to setup the sections to continue page numbering.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you're using the two column layout, but you could probably achieve similar results using a table with two columns.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the new section started new page numbering. Click in the section on page 21 (or wherever the new page numbering starts). The go to the Insert tab --> "Page Number" drop down --> and choose "Format Page Numbers".

At the bottom of that box, I'm guessing it is set to "Start at" and they probably chose "2". Instead set it to "Continue from previous section".